# Prevent text flowing onto new line?

Tags: html, css

I have paragraph text contained within a div that has a specific max-width pixel value.

The last word of this paragraph awkwardly begins a new line. I’d like to assign a class for this single word so it’s able to ignore the div restraints and overflow on the same line.

Is there a method of doing this? Thank you *!*

```
<div class="description"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>  


  .description p {
  max-width: 700px; }
```

In the example here, the word “elit” would stay on the same line no matter what.

Comment: you're looking for CSS `white-space: nowrap;` I guess...

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
p { white-space: nowrap; }
```

This code will make the text to be on one line.

Comment: This would make the whole paragraph a single line. The original question only wants to prevent the last word from being alone on a final line.

Comment: So please use `p span { white-space: nowrap; }`. If this doesn't help you please provide HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the immediate responses. I tried the above with no luck, I’m probably being extremely dumb.

`<p class="break">elit.</p>`
`.break p span { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: * `<span class="break">elit.</span>` having no affect either.

Comment: Just make 1px lower font-size and the text will fit in 700px wide container. If this doesn't help you please explain what exactly do you want to achieve and in what device width do you want to achieve it?

Comment: Which device are you using if it is desktop then increase the width of the paragraph -   `.description p { max-width: 750px; }`

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way of doing this with pure CSS, provided you do not wish the whole paragraph to be a single line.

You could replace the space character between the last two words with a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` in the html. Alternately place the last two words in a span that has `nowrap` set. Both of these approaches would make the last line a minimum of two words.

Comment: You, you can do it with CSS using `white-space: nowrap;`.

Comment: That would make the whole paragraph a single line. The original question only wants to prevent the last word from being alone on a final line. No mention is made of single-lining the whole paragraph.